# The rich playboy is dead, and he's a ghost, but his wife still loves him

Tags: story-identification, comics, magic, ghost

I remember this one comic book way back, in the 1990s, where a man in a blue ski outfit and his wife are out shopping to get the latest ski outfits. She gets this very sexy thing, in various colors of course, and the man says no thank you to the sales girl even though his outfit is a few years out of date.

Turns out this millionaire playboy is dead. He died in a plane crash. But he's still on earth, he didn't move on to the afterlife. People can see him, he can talk to people. But he's dead. The only clothes he can wear are those he died with, so while he can take off his jacket and shoes anything else isn't happening. He also can't eat, and he's hungry, because he's a ghost, and didn't eat on the plane before it crashed and burned. But using this dark, magic, shadow power he can levitate forks, touch his wife, and even pretend to skiboard by levitation.

So they go up to a cabin in the woods and ski down the mountain, like rich people on holiday. They're attacked by a ghost thing, and they flee. The man explains to his wife that he dosen't know what that this is, except that it's not whole. It's after him for his magic, dark shadow power, or something.

I didn't get the chance to read more of the comic. So what is it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This sounds similar to Valiant's original *The Second Life of Doctor Mirage*. The title character was Hwen Mirage, a doctor, his wife was Carmen Ruiz. He died in a white-and-black ski outfit, on vacation with his wife. However, he gained powers, could still be seen and heard, and was pursued (by Valiant's big villain, Master Darque), and became a superhero.

The white and black outfit tended to have light blue highlights, as you can see on the cover to the first issue:

[image: Cover to *The Second Life of Doctor Mirage* #1]

The comic ran for 18 issues in 1993-1995.

Comment: Yup. That's definitely it. Thankyou.